# 2 DNN filesystems pointing to the same database

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have setup a local installation of DNN7 using a database residing in another machine (sqlserver 2008).
I've tried to copy all the filesystem to a production server but keep the connection string the same, so use the exact same database.

I get the message

"The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty."

```
    <roleManager>
       <providers>
              <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

The application pool and IIS settings are the same in both machines. Any ideas of what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the role membership provider.
For some reason the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider provider falls back at the default one which is in the machine.config (insided the .NET folder).

In dev environments with an SQLEXpress instance running, the machine.config has a connection string named 'LocalSqlServer' which points to the SQLExpress. That's why it worked in my dev environment.

The server on the other hand, doesn't have SQLExpress, so no LocalSqlServer connectionstring exists in the machine.config and therefore the error pops up.

The workaround I found in DNN forums is to add these lines inside the  section of the **web**.config

```
 <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=dbserver;Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=dbName;User ID=dbUser;Password=dbPass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following section in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005/2008 Express -->
    
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005/2008
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: the connectionStrings exist, as I mentioned the web.config works as it is in the dev machine. I'm posting the solution in an answer